# Testing WebApp based on WebPack with HMTLWebPackPlugin falis on Bootstrap loading

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, webpack, mocha.js

I build an application using WebPack with its HMTLWebPackPluggn. I coded my unit test using **MochaJS** and I have to main problems I do not know how to solve:

As soon as I import Bootstrap library

```
import 'bootstrap';             // Bootstrap 4 LIB (JS)
```

i get following error after running my tests:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
    at Object.jQueryDetection (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:242:26)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:254:8)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:7:11)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:9:2)
```

If I import any module containing jQuery DOM manipulation like:

```
$(function() { ... }
```

I get the following error:

```
jQuery requires a window with a document
    at module.exports (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:31:12)
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./assets/inc/nav-bar.js:4:1)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./assets/inc/nav-bar.js:16:30)
```

If I remove Bootstrap import and do not use any jQuery then my unit tests run just fine.